# why is 2>$NULL not rerouting errors to NULL?

Tags: powershell

I have the following statement.

```
$CINPUT = $CINPUT.ToUpper() -replace '(^\s+|\s+$)','' -replace '\s+',' ' 2> $NULL
```

`2> $NULL` does not appear to be rerouting error to NULL at all, because i am still receiving exception.

> The variable cannot be validated because the value  is not a valid
>   value for the CINPUT variable.

i want to ignore the exception, and i dont know how to use `-ErrorAction Stop` in this case

Note: I am aware of it, and it works, but I dont want to use `-erroractionpreference` as global setting for my script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`2> $NULL` can only suppress errors written to the *PowerShell error stream*.

By contrast, your statement causes a *.NET exception*, which manifests as a *statement-terminating error* in PowerShell, which you can handle with `try` / `catch`:

```
try {
  $CINPUT = $CINPUT.ToUpper() -replace '(^\s+|\s+$)','' -replace '\s+',' '
} catch {} # ignore the statement-terminating error
```

Generally, a redirection of the error stream - `2>` - will only succeed if the command only produces *non-terminating* errors.

When invoking *external programs*, `2>` redirects their *stderr* output.

Comment: btw, if you dont mind, can you tell me how can i redirect output from this command to a variable? Restore-ASDatabase -Server $Server -RestoreFile $File -Name $CINPUT -Security:$Choice -AllowOverwrite -ErrorAction Stop

Comment: @Cataster: you can assign a `try` / `catch` statement directly to a variable. If a statement-terminating error occurs and the `catch` block produces no output, `$null` is assigned; e..g, `$var = try { 1 / 0 } catch {}`

Comment: so theer is no way i can do something like this? ASDatabase -Server $Server -RestoreFile $File -Name $CINPUT -Security:$Choice -AllowOverwrite -ErrorAction Stop >$var

Comment: @Cataster. No, but you can use the common `-OutVariable` parameter to capture a cmdlet's output. Note that it always creates a collection, if no statement-terminating error occurs; if there is a statement-terminating error, the target variable won't get assigned to at all.

Comment: sweet, -ov worked, and i found your post where you listed a workaround for -ov,

Comment: oh looks like it doesnt create a collection for me. i am using version PSVersion                      5.1.14393.2969

Comment: The same issue seem to be for using `cl`. For example, doing this: `echo // > foo.cpp; cl /nologo /Zc:preprocessor /PD /TC foo.cpp |sort; rm foo.cpp, foo.obj`, always spits out the link error. `LINK : fatal error LNK1561: entry point must be defined`. So it seem that `cl` doesn't actually send this to stderr.

Comment: @not2qubit, yes, it looks like `cl.exe` is ill-behaved and prints its error message to stdout instead of stderr, which is unfortunate. At least the exit code reflects the failure, however.

Comment: ...and for those wanting to use that, you can of course avoid getting the error by not linking using `/c`.